# Invalid data with Postman and dummy.io

Tags: post, postman, dummy-data

I’m trying to create a new user on dummyapi.io using Postman, but I keep getting a PARAMS_NOT_VALID error. I’m sending a POST request to the /user/create route with the firstName, lastName, and email fields in the request body, but I keep getting the same error. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue? Are there any additional fields I should include or any specific values I should send? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was trying to enter the data in Json format

```
{
  "firstName": "Juan",
  "lastName": "Pérez",
  "email": "juan.perez@example.com"
}
```

This is the error that rings the request in postman

```
{
    "error": "PARAMS_NOT_VALID"
}
```

Here's what the dummyapi.io documentation says:

```
Create User
Create new user, return created user data.
Body: User Create (firstName, lastName, email are required)
POST
/user/create
Response: User
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have:

- valid `app-id` HTTP request header set
- valid URL: `https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user/create`
- expected request method: `POST`
- `Content-Type` header should be set to `application/json` (in Postman select `Body -> Raw -> JSON (from the dropdown)`)
- a valid request body (see below)

[image: Set content-type in Postman version 10.16 on Linux]

I've tested the following request with success both in `curl` and Postman:

```bash
curl --location 'https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/user/create' \
--header 'app-id: <replace-with-your-app-id>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "firstName": "myFirstname",
  "lastName": "myLastname",
  "email": "my.email@example.com"
}'
```

You can either just run the `curl` command or import it into Postman using `Import` and then just paste the command.

[image: Import into Postman on Postman version 10.16 on Linux]

Expected result should be something along the lines of this:

Status `200 Ok`

```json
{
    "id": "64d515120dc40b433a86eb5f",
    "firstName": "myFirstname",
    "lastName": "myLastname",
    "email": "my.email@example.com",
    "registerDate": "2023-08-10T16:49:22.275Z",
    "updatedDate": "2023-08-10T16:49:22.275Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when I set "https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/" as a baseURL variable and added "/user/create" to the URL, so the URL became "https://dummyapi.io/data/v1//user/create" (with double slash). It obviously did not work until I removed the last slash from the baseURL variable.
So check your URL syntax also